# Find a smallest positive real number in an Tensor7?

Tags: lua, torch

If I have  4D Tensor and the Tensor contains real numbers

Could you please tell how to  find the smallest positive number greater than zero in the tensor

for example I have:

```
[ 0     -1     -3

6      5      0

0.3    0.6    0.9]
```

Here the smallest positive number greater than zero  is 0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = torch.Tensor({{0, -1, -3}, {6, 5, 0}, {0.3, 0.6, 0.9}})
minpos = torch.min(t[t:gt(0)])

0.3
```

**How to get index(es) of desired element(s):**

1) Create the mask

```
mask = t:eq(minpos)

 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 1  0  0
[torch.ByteTensor of size 3x3]
```

2) Somehow get the indexes of non-zero elements of the mask. For example, using this function:

```
function indexesOf(mask)
    local lin_indices = torch.linspace(1, mask:nElement(), mask:nElement())[mask]
    if lin_indices:nElement() == 0 then return nil end

    local sp_indices = torch.LongTensor(mask:nDimension(), lin_indices:nElement())
    sp_indices[1] = lin_indices - 1
    local divisor = mask:nElement()
    for d = 1, mask:nDimension() - 1 do
        divisor = divisor / mask:size(d)
        local fdiv = torch.div(sp_indices[d], divisor)
        sp_indices[d + 1] = sp_indices[d] - fdiv * divisor
        sp_indices[d] = fdiv
    end
    return sp_indices:t() + 1
end

indexes = indexesOf(mask)

 3  1
[torch.LongTensor of size 1x2]
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility:

```
t = { 0,  -1,  -3,
      6,   5,   0,
      0.3, 0.6, 0.9 }

temp = {}
for _,n in ipairs(t) do
  if n > 0 then               --keep only positives
    temp[#temp+1] = n
  end
end
table.sort(temp)              --sorting them will bring the smallest first

print('Answer',temp[1])
```

UPDATE: To also find the position at which the lowest value occurs, modify the above to this:

```
t = { 0,  -1,  -3,
      6,   5,   0,
      0.3, 0.6, 0.9 }

temp = {}
for i,n in ipairs(t) do
  if n > 0 then               --keep only positives
    temp[#temp+1] = { n = n, p = i}
  end
end
table.sort(temp,function(a,b) return a.n < b.n end)      --sorting them will bring the smallest first

print('Answer '.. temp[1].n ..' at position '.. temp[1].p)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
t = { 0,  -1,  -3,
      6,   5,   0,
      0.3, 0.6, 0.9 }

for _,n in ipairs(t) do
  if n > 0 then               --only for positives
    if ans == nil then
      ans = n                 --first positive assumed lowest
    else
      if n < ans then ans = n end  --if a lower value is found, replaces previous one
    end
  end
end

print('Answer',ans)
```

UPDATE: To also find the position at which the lowest value occurs, modify the above to this:

```
t = { 0,  -1,  -3,
      6,   5,   0,
      0.3, 0.6, 0.9 }

for i,n in ipairs(t) do
  if n > 0 then               --only for positives
    if ans == nil then
      ans = n                 --first positive assumed lowest
      pos = i
    else
      if n < ans then         --if a lower value is found, replaces previous one
        ans = n
        pos = i               --keep position
      end
    end
  end
end

print('Answer '.. ans ..' at position '.. pos)
```

Comment: many thanks I have other equation please. I want to return the indices or position of that number (smallest one) in the original matrix or table.